# Django no object matches the given query but it should

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-channels

I have the following problem my database is not empty and has the record that I need. But when I query the db it says that there is no such object matching the given query. I query the db from within a websocket using django-channels and my database is postgreSQL.

**I am aware that there are other questions about this and I looked into them but they are all about empty database or wrong url slug which is not my case and doesn't help me with anything**

Here is the corresponding code:

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_receive(message):
    username = message.user.username
    print(username)
    text = json.loads(message['text']).get('text')
    # Use my algorithm here
    score = score_argument.get_rating(text)
    # find the room with our users

    current_room = get_object_or_404(PairUsers, Q(username_a=username) | Q(username_b=username))

    # current_room = PairUsers.objects.filter(Q(username_a=username) | Q(username_b=username)).first()

    # check which user you got and send the message to the other
    if current_room.username_b == username:
        current_room.score_b = score
        other_channel = Channel(current_room.reply_channel_a)
        message.reply_channel.send({'text': text})
        other_channel.send({'text': text})
    else:
        current_room.score_a = score
        other_channel = Channel(current_room.reply_channel_b)
        message.reply_channel.send({'text': text})
        other_channel.send({'text': text})
```

Another thing that I noticed is that the print(username) does not print anything it just skips this line. I used message.user.username in different function that works so I am sure it should return the username

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35\lib\site-packages\channels\worker.py", line 119, in run
    consumer(message, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 180, in inner
    result = func(message, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35\lib\site-packages\channels\auth.py", line 73, in inner
    return func(message, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 64, in inner
    return func(message, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35\lib\site-packages\channels\auth.py", line 89, in inner
    return func(message, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nithe\Desktop\debateit\play\consumers.py", line 51, in ws_receive
    current_room = get_object_or_404(PairUsers, Q(username_a=username) | Q(username_b=username))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 93, in get_object_or_404
    raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model._meta.object_name)
django.http.response.Http404: No PairUsers matches the given query.
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Comment: @RaphaëlGomès done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.user.username` appears to be `None`, your query will of course fail. This question is not a database problem (yet), it's `channels` related.
Try printing your `message.user.__dict__`, see if it matches the object you expect.

Comment: It prints empty dictionary which means that it does not record the user sending it?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your `websocket` connection yes. But that's for another question, I think. Provide all your files (routing, any js you have, etc.) there.